# Does Scala's Vector add any new methods on top of those provided by Seq and other superclasses?

Tags: scala, vector, localization

Are there any methods in Scala's Vector that are not declared by its superclasses like AbstractSeq?

I am working on providing language localization (translation) for a learning environment/IDE built on top of Scala called Kojo (see kojo.in). I have translated most commonly used methods of Seq. Vector inherits them automatically, so I don't need to duplicated the translation code (keeping DRY). E.g.,

```
  implicit class TurkishTranslationsForSeqMethods[T](s: Seq[T]) {
    def başı: T = s.head
    def kuyruğu: Seq[T] = s.tail
    def boyu: Int = s.length
    def boşMu: Boolean = s.isEmpty
    // ...
  }
  implicit class TranslationsForVectorMethods[T](v: Vector[T]) {
    ??? // what to translate here?
  }
```

Hence the question. Maybe, more importantly, is there a way to find out such novel additions for any class without having to do a manual diff?

Comment: ugh ... I wonder how much demand is out there realistically, for people who can write scala code but only in Turkish :/

Comment: :-) It is only a choice and for educational purposes. Kojo supports English/Swedish/Spanish/Italian/German/Turkish/... Even when the user switches to Turkish, English commands are still available...

Answer (score 1):

The **scaladoc** provides a way to filter methods to not see the ones inherited from `Seq` for instance: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html a'd click on *"Filter all members"*.

Or, probably easier, **IDE**s usually provide a "Hierarchy" view of a class and its methods that would give you the information quickly.

Comment: Once I clicked on "Filter all members", I saw that there is a binary option: Alphabetical vs By Inheritance. Selecting the latter did the trick. By the way, I can now confirm that all the methods of Vector are inherited.